# Moving a secondary hard drive from one machine to another maintaining installed software

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I'm in the process of re-building my PC, and due to my current windows having an OEM license I'm doing a new windows installation. My current setup is two hard-drives:

1x750gb, partitioned into

- 100gb for C:\ - Mostly windows and anything that doesn't allow/respect change to default install path
- 650gb for D:\ - Media

1x1Tb with single partition

What I want to do is move the 1Tb onto the new machine, which I know will work from a hardware perspective, however it holds most of the installed software I use that I don't particularly want to have to re-[download/install], but my new Windows installation won't know about any of them.

I'm guessing it won't be as easy as exporting the entire registry from the original Windows, and importing it into the new installation (which will probably cause more problems than it would cause). Or is it just safer to bite the bullet, get a new secondary hdd, and just start from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Portable apps will function as normal, you'll just need to create new shortcuts.

The vast majority of apps this won't work for, registry files/config files, stuff in %APPDATA%, firewall permissions etc will all cause weird behavior.

Use ninite to rapidly re-install any mainstream stuff and manually do anything it doesnt include.